# Magento 2 pages and blocks not loading in backend

Tags: magento-2.1

After restoring a backup of Magento 2, the pages and blocks won't load in the backend. It keeps loading and loading without not showing any pages or blocks. I reindex, compile, clear cache... But nothing changed. Any help would be much appreciated. Screenshot here http://prntscr.com/cavr3k

Thank you!